# how to back track docker hub image to github repository

Tags: github, reverse-engineering, dockerhub

i have a dockerhub image, i can open it and view content using

`docker exec -it  sh.`

fine, but how do i track the same image to the content build from github repository.

back track a pipe line that had converted github repository code from which version ? to docker hub  image.

Thanks

Comment: There's no guarantee that there is any public repository that contains the deockerfile.

Comment: docker image can be inspected using dive tool or exec sh, thats fine suppose i want the source code of the image downloaded how can i track that. monolithic application have war file or we will provided with jboss server location. so i can see content replace class files etc we can decompile class files etc ..but how in microservices ?